# formula in ios application how to create it

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Please, i have this formula here:

```
=((r/100/12)*amt)/(1-((1+(r/100/12)^(-period)))
```

Could someone help me with how to convert it in a formula for objective c?
I need the final formula..

What i use:

```
double int_ = ([Norma_value floatValue]/100)/12;
double months = -[kohezgjatja_value floatValue];
double r1 = pow(int_, months);
double pt1 = 1 + r1;
double pt2 = 1- pt1;

double pmt = ([shuma_value floatValue]* int_)/pt2;


balanca.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f €",pmt];
```

Comment: There is nothing to do other than define `r`, `amt` and `period` of the correct type (integer or float) and assign them some values.

Comment: Assuming you mean 'to the power of' with `^`, the only thing you should change is that symbol and put in `pow(double,double)`, after doing what @trojanfoe states.

Comment: but does the ^ work? isn't there needed a pow function?..

Comment: @trojanfoe No, there is no exponent operator.

Comment: yes, if i use float for large amounts it won't work...
yes, so please, could you just tell me how should i write it..

Comment: could you please take a look at my updated question, i have no idea why the result is -0.00

Comment: What are the values of Norma_value, kohezgjatja_value and shuma_value?

Comment: so norma value is a number something like 4,5,6 or it can be 4.5 while shuma is an integer aswell , an amount like 200.000 and kohezgjatja is the number of months

Comment: By the way, you really should not be using `double` for currency....  "Bad things" (tm) can happen with rounding, etc.  Look at `NSDecimalNumber` instead.

Comment: could you please show me an example, i looked at it in google, but an example of how to save one of my variables with the method you suggested..

Comment: kohezgjatja_value ?? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula you've written should work in objective c except for the `^` part.

To implement `x ^ y` in objective c you can use:

```
pow(x,y)
```

Take a look at this question as reference for pow: [How to raise a double value by power of 12?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816055/how-to-raise-a-double-value-by-power-of-12)

Comment: could you please take a look at my updated question, i have no idea why the result is -0.00

Comment: Try to print out with NSLog after every line to see which fails. I suspect that pow fails, because it's casting to ints. See the question I linked to for explanation on how to make it work on doubles well.

Comment: Also calculate it with a regular calculator and make sure the result isn't something like 0.0002 because this will be rounded to 0.00 in the stringWithFormat

Comment: the pmt variable fails on me, when i substract..

Comment: Can you print the values of all vars in the failed run?

Comment: it's not like it fails, is just that it brings out 0.00