# Mathematical operation in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How to find the result for a^b in Objective C? For example, 2^3 = 8. How to perform that in Objective C? Any shortcuts other than writing my own methods?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816055/how-to-raise-a-double-value-by-power-of-12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the C function pow(x,y);

```
double res = pow(5.0,2.0); //25
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `pow(x, y)` function.